# collectd perl plugin data in subdirs

Tags: perl, collectd

Im writing custom collecd plugin in perl.
Lets say it for network monitoring "netmonit".
So I'm sending data like that :

```
server-group.server.netmonit.net1_counter1
server-group.server.netmonit.net1_counter2
server-group.server.netmonit.net2_counter1
server-group.server.netmonit.net2_counter2
```

My question is if i can send data to subdirs :

```
server-group.server.netmonit.net1.counter1
server-group.server.netmonit.net1.counter2
server-group.server.netmonit.net2.counter1
server-group.server.netmonit.net2.counter2

use Collectd qw( :all )
...
...
sub read_data_netmonit {
    my $va = { type => 'absolute', plugin => netmonit };
    my $data = get_data();
    for my $metric (@metrics) {
        $va->{'values'}        = [ $data->{$metric} ];
        $va->{'type_instance'} = "$metric";
        plugin_dispatch_values($va);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: example that i show here puts everything in one directory.
I'd like to know if someone has example with subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

In collectd there is no such thing as "sending data to directories". Collectd simply collects numbers and assigns them a unique identifier built using 5 components:

- host
- plugin
- plugin-instance
- type
- type-instance

There is even a 6th component which is the data-source.

What you seem to be referring to is the write plugin `write_graphite`, which will take those identifiers and metrics, and use them to create directories where the data points will be stored.

Collectd is limited to those five levels I showed, so you'll have to do the magic on graphite's side.